# 2ое меню с на сайте

Tags: html, css

Я хочу создать второе меню через `ul li a`, но у него совсем другие стили и оформление. Как мне быть? Я пробовал подключить отдельную php-страницу, а к ней уже непосредственно вторую таблицу стилей с описанием тех же `ul li a`, в итоге вторая таблица стилей ломает мне первое меню.

Comment: Ну так создайте меню и пропишите им соответствующие css стили. Изменяйте имена стилей.

Comment: дай этим менюшкам разные классы и обращайся к ним через класс например .sidebar-menu li {color:red;} .menu li {color:blue;}

Comment: а как быть с a.hover { когда для него прописываю стили портится перове меню

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте идентификатор или класс корневому эдементу меню и прописывайте стили, начиная с этого идентификатора / класса. например:

```
<ul class="first">
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>


<ul class="second">
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>

.first li a {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.second li a {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую. большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Создайте другую html-разметку, другие классы/идентификаторы, пропишите стили. Пример:

```css
.menu li {
  color: blue;
}

.menu2 li {
  color: green;
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  Меню 1
  <ul>
    <li>Пункт 1,1</li>
    <li>Пункт 1,1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu2">
  Меню 2
  <ul>
    <li>Пункт 1,1</li>
    <li>Пункт 1,1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```